# Background-image not working nicely with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, background, sticky-footer, skeleton-css-boilerplate

So, with my current HTML and CSS set-up, the background image for my content breaks for my footer, which is not exactly what I want. Case and point: http://droppinghike.nl/gallerij.html

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1 id="title">Dropping Hike</h1>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a class="nav-link" id="active" href="#">Home<div class="nav-underline"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="aanmelden.html">Aanmelden<div class="nav-underline"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="deelnemers.html">Deelnemers<div class="nav-underline"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallerij.html">Gallerij<div class="nav-underline"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact<div class="nav-underline"></div></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">FAQ<div class="nav-underline"></div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="section">Welkom</h3>
        <p style="text-align: justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult, salvam esse se, quod concedimus; Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono. Negat esse eam, inquit, propter se expetendam. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Itaque primos congressus copulationesque et consuetudinum instituendarum voluntates fieri propter voluptatem; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Nam quid possumus facere melius? Hoc non est positum in nostra actione. An ea, quae per vinitorem antea consequebatur, per se ipsa curabit? Duarum enim vitarum nobis erunt instituta capienda. An hoc usque quaque, aliter in vita? Callipho ad virtutem nihil adiunxit nisi voluptatem, Diodorus vacuitatem doloris. Est autem etiam actio quaedam corporis, quae motus et status naturae congruentis tenet; Laelius clamores sofòw ille so lebat Edere compellans gumias ex ordine nostros. Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. Immo vero, inquit, ad beatissime vivendum parum est, ad beate vero satis. Vos autem cum perspicuis dubia debeatis illustrare, dubiis perspicua conamini tollere. Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono. Eademne, quae restincta siti? Nunc ita separantur, ut disiuncta sint, quo nihil potest esse perversius. Ego quoque, inquit, didicerim libentius si quid attuleris, quam te reprehenderim. Equidem e Cn.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="section">Thema</h3>
        <p style="text-align: justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult, salvam esse se, quod concedimus; Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono. Negat esse eam, inquit, propter se expetendam. Post enim Chrysippum eum non sane est disputatum. Itaque primos congressus copulationesque et consuetudinum instituendarum voluntates fieri propter voluptatem; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Nam quid possumus facere melius? Hoc non est positum in nostra actione. An ea, quae per vinitorem antea consequebatur, per se ipsa curabit? Duarum enim vitarum nobis erunt instituta capienda. An hoc usque quaque, aliter in vita? Callipho ad virtutem nihil adiunxit nisi voluptatem, Diodorus vacuitatem doloris. Est autem etiam actio quaedam corporis, quae motus et status naturae congruentis tenet; Laelius clamores sofòw ille so lebat Edere compellans gumias ex ordine nostros. Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. Immo vero, inquit, ad beatissime vivendum parum est, ad beate vero satis. Vos autem cum perspicuis dubia debeatis illustrare, dubiis perspicua conamini tollere. Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono. Eademne, quae restincta siti? Nunc ita separantur, ut disiuncta sint, quo nihil potest esse perversius. Ego quoque, inquit, didicerim libentius si quid attuleris, quam te reprehenderim. Equidem e Cn.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="one-third column">
            <h5 class="section"><span class="fa-stack"><i style="color:#1e824c" class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> Uitdagend</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult, salvam esse se, quod concedimus; Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <h5 class="section"><span class="fa-stack"><i style="color:#1e824c" class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-beer fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> Gezellig</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult, salvam esse se, quod concedimus; Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <h5 class="section"><span class="fa-stack"><i style="color:#1e824c" class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-flag-checkered fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span> Competitief</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult, salvam esse se, quod concedimus; Ita graviter et severe voluptatem secrevit a bono.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="u-full-width"> <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <p style="text-align: center">© 2016 Dropping Hike. Alle rechten voorbehouden.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**My CSS:**

```
    html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(../images/boom-schors-texture.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.container {
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    background: url(../images/white_wall_hash.png);
    min-height: 100%;
}
a {
  color: #1e824c; }
a:hover { 
  color: #a3c338; }
p {
    text-align: justify;  }
.section {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #1e824c;}
.underline {
  border-width: 0;
  width: 64px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1e824c;  }
.nav-underline {
  width:0;
  height:2px;
  background:#1e824c;
  transition:width 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition:width 0.5s;  }
a.nav-link:hover > .nav-underline {
  width:100%;  }
a.nav-link#active > .nav-underline {
  width:100%;  }
a.nav-link:hover {
  color: #000;  }
a.nav-link { 
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;  }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #1e824c;
  color: #000; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #1e824c;
  background-color: #1e824c; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #1e824c;
  outline: 0; }
#nav {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 3rem;  }
#nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;  }
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #1e824c;
  font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
header {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
hr {
    border-width: 0;
    width: 90%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1e824c;  }
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the default top margin from the footer's hr:

```
hr {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Currently the default hr pushes the whole footer down below where it should be.

If you want to keep the space between the content and the footer on longer pages, you can add a `<br />` between the main container and the footer here:

[image]

**Edit:**
To make the main content full height instead of pushing the footer to the bottom:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it seems to solve the issue on pages with enough content to cover the page vertically, but in the case of pages with very little content, I am still stuck with this big gap: [link](http://droppinghike.nl/gallerij.html)

Comment: You mean you don't want it to go to the bottom but to just stay 30 px below the content? 
 
In this case you can do `footer { position: static; margin-top: 30px; }`

Comment: No, that is perfectly fine. I want the white background to cover the entire page vertically however, I don't want there to be a break in that, but I don't exactly know how to achieve this.

Comment: Hmm, I want both the footer to stick to the bottom while also make the make content full height. With your suggested edit, it does not work on pages with a bit more content, see: [link](http://droppinghike.nl/aanmelden.html)

Comment: Hmm yes.. You can change: 
`.container {min-height: 100%;}`
and make the footer not absolute to make this work:
`footer {position: static; }`
However you will have full height content box on smaller pages, and the footer will be below the fold.
Another option would be to include the footer in the main container, make it absolute, and give the main container 100px bottom padding.

Comment: Yes, I have managed to get it all working now, thanks a lot! :)